# Invalid geometry error when running Vector Intersection tool in QGIS 3

Tags: geoprocessing, qgis-3

I am reworking an exercise that runs fine in QGIS 2.14 and 2.18 but have encountered an error in QGIS 3.2. I am using Windows 8.

I am using the Alaska training data and adding the majrivers and trees shapefiles. I select the Susitna River, which works fine and then set a buffer of 5000 around it. Here are the steps I am using in QGIS 3.2 (steps 3,4 and 5 
were not needed in QGIS 2.18)

1. Processing Toolbox/Vector Selection/Select by Attribute (set Description = Susitna River) and it highlights
2. Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Buffer ( input is majrivers, check the selected features only and dissolve, distance = 5000)
3. Processing tools/Vector Geometry/Fix Geometries on the buffer layer
4. Processing Tools/Vector Geometry/Check Validity
5. Processing Tools/Vector Geometry/Remove Null Geometries
6. Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Intersection (Input layer is fixed geometries, intersection layer is trees)

The following error occurs when running intersection:

```
Feature (118) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.16 seconds
```

Are there other tools that can correct the invalid geometry for feature 118?

Comment: I think this post will help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290470/invalid-geometries-in-qgis-3-seems-to-be-more-prevalent-than-qgis-2. One weird trick that has worked for me is grass buffer of 0.